Shrink address bar on Safari for mobile - JavaScript
Seen a lot of old threads (thread 1 and thread 2) but hasn't been discussed lately, since the latest iOs deprecated the use of scrollTo and minimal-ui, requiring manual (human) scroll in order to shrink the address bar, is there any way around it so we can shrink the address bar on page loading, not requiring the user to manually scroll to shrink? Tried scrollTo, minimal-ui, "display": "standalone", "orientation": "portrait", in manifest.json however still hadn't had luck. Any feedback is appreciated? page example I've been working with scrollTo

Sounds like a great way to annoy your users. Change your design to work with the way the browser works, rather than trying to override the browser design. Why do you want the address bar to be shrunk on page load?

Hi, thanks for your comment. The address bar is shrunk after the first scrolling down by the user anyway, It's a game that is primarily for larger breakpoints but wanted to make it compatible with mobile breakpoints as well. With the shrunking of the address bar the canvas is bigger which makes the UI better.
